# How to make Google reCAPTCHA 100% wide

Tags: html, css

I tried using `width: 100%` on `rc-anchor` and `g-recaptcha`, I also tried `width: 100%!important`, which didn't work either. I tried the trick: `transform: scale(0.77)`, but once again, it didn't work, how can I make the captcha container 100% width of the parent?

There's no code to show because it's as simple as:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykey"></div>
```

Comment: [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykey" style="transform:scale(2.5);-webkit-transform:scale(2.5);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"></div>
```

Play with the `transform: scale();` and `transform-origin: 0 0;`. It worked on mine.